# How to create animation on asp:Image control?

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, vb.net

I actually have a header banner on my page which randomly changes every 9 seconds. But changes happen in a flash. I would like to add a fade animation effect or any smooth effect while the banner image changes.

I have asp.net code below for this purpose-

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="9000" Enabled="True"></asp:Timer>
    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" CssClass ="slider"/>
</ContentTemplate>
```

My vb code page has below code-

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        SetImageUrl()
    End If
End Sub

'Image slide show
Private Sub SetImageUrl()
    Dim _rand As New Random()
    Dim i As Integer = _rand.[Next](1, 6)
    Image1.ImageUrl = "~/images/banner/" & i.ToString() & ".jpg"
End Sub

Protected Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    SetImageUrl()

End Sub
```

Can anyone please give me any solution that might work with this code setup?

Comment: From the example you gave, it seems that you have an image slideshow that refreshes every few seconds. In this scenarion the jQuery Cycle2 (http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) plugin would be more fitting.

If you want to want to keep your current code setup, this link might give you a solution: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398866%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: You are right! Ok i will give it a try and see how does it go.

Comment: @TasosK. Cycle2 looks really good. But I am not sure how to randomize that slideshow! All the demos they have are in order. cycle2 would a good solution for me but if i can just randomize the slideshow at every page load.

Comment: It has a `random` property, check it out here http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/

Comment: Thanks. I used previous version of cycle which is working fine for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here's the solution which i'm using now. I have completely removed ajax and asp.net controls and instead used html  with jQuery cycle http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ Thanks to TasosK for the heads up. I somehow lost the actual link of stack from where i borrowed few lines of code-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.my-slideshow').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 3000,
    timeout: 1,
    startingSlide: Math.floor(Math.random() * 6), // where 6 is the slidecount
    containerResize: 0,
    before: function (currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
        var container = $(this).parent();
        container.css('height', Math.max(container.height(), $(nextSlideElement).height()));
    },
    after: function (currSlideElement, nextSlideElement, options, forwardFlag) {
        $(this).parent().css('height', $(this).height());
    }
});
```

```
<div class="my-slideshow">
<img src="images/banner/1.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/banner/2.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/banner/3.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/banner/4.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="images/banner/5.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```